# Reputation points for commenting?

Tags: discussion, comment, reputation

Forgive me as this is an elementary question.  I thought I remembered that you used to get 1 point for someone upvoting your comment.  I notice that this doesn't happen anymore.  So did this used to happen and if so, when did it get changed so you don't get points for good comments anymore.

Comment: Note, however, [the silver Pundit badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for 10 Comments with 5 or more upvotes.

Comment: I highly doubt it has ever been the case.  There was even some reticence towards simply allowing users to _upvote comments_ in the beginning.   (There is also a recent [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/214632) on MSO with no mention of this having been the case in the past.)

Answer (score 16):

As far as I know, this was never the case.

Comment: Certainly not during my time here.

Comment: And certainly not since I'm a member of the site.